# How to get class name with orm_class on custom scaffold generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making custom templates to help the development on our application and I got stuck in a silly issue.

I am trying to put the ransack parameter in the index action controller but I cant make the generator spell only the classname.

The default controler is

```
  def index
    @<%= plural_table_name %> = <%= orm_class.all(class_name) %>
  end
```

Which will produce a thing like:

```
  def index
    @stuffs = Stuff.all
  end
```

What I want is something like:

```
  def index
    @search = <%= orm_class.search(class_name, params[:q]) %>
    @<%= plural_table_name %> = @search.result.order('id')
      .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
  end
```

that would produce:

```
def index
    @search = Stuff.search(params[:q])
    @stuffs = @search.result.order('id')
      .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
end
```

The thing is, orm_class doesn't have a search method.
I could solve this if the function give me only "Classname" but if I try
orm_class alone, it return in the code "Rails::Generators::ActiveModel".

How can I make the orm_class give me only "Classname"?

The "best" I've come so far was

```
@search = <%= orm_class.all(class_name) %>.search(params[:q])
```

But then I have manually remove the "all" after I generate the scaffold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ActiveSupport::Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html) adds a variety of methods for transforming strings. You want `classify`:

```
plural_table_name.classify
```

For example:

```
> "my_stuffs".classify
=> "MyStuff"
```

In your case:

```
@<%= plural_table_name %> = <%= plural_table_name.classify %>.search(params[:q])
```